# Delete matching files from script

Tags: shell-script, find

Couldn't piece together why this happens. In this folder `/usr/local/nginx/html` I want to delete all or `sky21.ts`, `sky22.ts`, ... to `sky29.ts`.
If I run this command directly in the folder

```
find /usr/local/nginx/html -type f -name 'sky2*.ts' -delete
```

it works and only deletes the matching `ts` files but when ran from a script in `/home/ubuntu` it deletes the `sky2.m3u8` file along with the `stream.png` thumbnail.

What is going on? Could the same command return something else inside the script? Am I going insane?

Here's my script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "run" ]; then
        source $HOME/.bash_aliases
        find /usr/local/nginx/html -type f -name 'sky2*.ts' -print > someFile.txt
 #      while [ 1 ]; do 
#ffmpeg -v verbose -i rtmp://ip:1935/live1/sky-2 -c copy -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 /usr/local/nginx/html/sky2.m3u8
#        done
else
        killall -9 ffmpeg > /dev/null 2>&1
        sleep 5s;
        screen -ls | grep sky2 > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ "$?" = "1" ]; then
                screen -mdS sky2 $0 run
        fi
fi
```

And this is the output of find with `-print`

```
/usr/local/nginx/html/sky24.ts
/usr/local/nginx/html/sky21.ts
/usr/local/nginx/html/sky23.ts
/usr/local/nginx/html/sky28.ts
/usr/local/nginx/html/sky27.ts
/usr/local/nginx/html/sky22.ts
/usr/local/nginx/html/sky25.ts
/usr/local/nginx/html/sky26.ts
/usr/local/nginx/html/sky29.ts
```

Comment: Try debugging by replacing `-delete` with `-print` and seeing what the output is, perhaps?

Comment: What does that script contain, exactly, and how do you run it?

Comment: It's just running ffmpeg inside a screen , Here's an example https://gist.github.com/cAstraea/c3b876957e761a15e31e043db5f1d463

Comment: IMO odds are 1. Something is in `$HOME/.bash_aliases` that overrides the behaviour of `find`; 2. you're not running the script you think you're running; 3. the missing files weren't there in the first place (i.e. it's not your `find` that deleted them)